# TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'ime.registIMEKey()')

Tags: samsung-smart-tv

Despite of setting and defining everything in Samsung smart TV SDK 4.0 I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'ime.registIMEKey()')
```

Please help!

```
CODE:

var widgetAPI = new Common.API.Widget();
var tvKey = new Common.API.TVKeyValue();

var wapal_magic =
{
    elementIds: new Array(),
    inputs: new Array(),
    ready: new Array()
};
/////////////////////////
var Input = function (id, previousId, nextId) {
    var previousElement = document.getElementById(previousId),
    nextElement = document.getElementById(nextId);

    var installFocusKeyCallbacks = function () {
    ime.setKeyFunc(tvKey.KEY_UP, function (keyCode) {
        previousElement.focus();
        return false;
    });
    ime.setKeyFunc(tvKey.KEY_DOWN, function (keyCode) {
        nextElement.focus();
        return false;
    });
    ime.setKeyFunc(tvKey.KEY_RETURN, function (keyCode) {
        widgetAPI.blockNavigation();
        return false;
    });
    ime.setKeyFunc(tvKey.KEY_EXIT, function (keyCode) {
        widgetAPI.blockNavigation();
        return false;
    });
}

    var imeReady = function (imeObject) {
        installFocusKeyCallbacks();
        wapal_magic.ready(id);
    },
    ime = new IMEShell(id, imeReady, 'en'),
    element = document.getElementById(id);
}

wapal_magic.createInputObjects = function () {
    var index,
        previousIndex,
        nextIndex;

    for (index in this.elementIds) {
        previousIndex = index - 1;
        if (previousIndex < 0) {
            previousIndex = wapal_magic.inputs.length - 1;
        }
        nextIndex = (index + 1) % wapal_magic.inputs.length;
        wapal_magic.inputs[index] = new Input(this.elementIds[index],
                this.elementIds[previousIndex], this.elementIds[nextIndex]);
    }
};

wapal_magic.ready = function (id) {
    var ready = true,
    i;

    for (i in wapal_magic.elementIds) {
        if (wapal_magic.elementIds[i] == id) {
            wapal_magic.ready[i] = true;
        }

        if (wapal_magic.ready[i] == false) {
            ready = false;
        }
    }
    if (ready) {
        document.getElementById("txtInp1").focus();
    }
};
////////////////////////
wapal_magic.onLoad = function()
{
    // Enable key event processing
    //this.enableKeys();
   // widgetAPI.sendReadyEvent();

    this.initTextBoxes(new Array("txtInp1", "txtInp2"));



};
wapal_magic.initTextBoxes = function(textboxes){
    this.elementIds = textboxes;
    for(i=0;i<this.elementIds.length;i++){
        this.inputs[i]=false;
        this.ready[i]=null;
    }

        this.createInputObjects();
    widgetAPI.registIMEKey();
};
wapal_magic.onUnload = function()
{

};

wapal_magic.enableKeys = function()
{
    document.getElementById("anchor").focus();
};

wapal_magic.keyDown = function()
{
    var keyCode = event.keyCode;
    alert("Key pressed: " + keyCode);

    switch(keyCode)
    {
        case tvKey.KEY_RETURN:
        case tvKey.KEY_PANEL_RETURN:
            alert("RETURN");
            widgetAPI.sendReturnEvent();
            break;
        case tvKey.KEY_LEFT:
            alert("LEFT");
            break;
        case tvKey.KEY_RIGHT:
            alert("RIGHT");
            break;
        case tvKey.KEY_UP:
            alert("UP");
            break;
        case tvKey.KEY_DOWN:
            alert("DOWN");
            break;
        case tvKey.KEY_ENTER:
        case tvKey.KEY_PANEL_ENTER:
            alert("ENTER");
            break;
        default:
            alert("Unhandled key");
            break;
    }
};
```

Comment: Post edited. See the code. Thanks

Comment: code you posted did not contain `ime.registIMEKey()` mentioned in error message

Comment: LOL...registIMEKey() the API built-in function

Comment: and this is function of `pluginApi`, not `ime`

Answer (score 1):

The registIMEKey method is part of the Plugin API.

```
var pluginAPI = new Common.API.Plugin();
pluginAPI.registIMEKey();
```

See: http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/ref00006/common_module_plugin_object.html#ref00006-common-module-plugin-object-registimekey

Edit: Updated to add code solution.

Comment: [Answers that are just links should be comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: Thanks for the advice.
The answer to the problem is in the comment. Link is there for reference.

Answer (score 0):

widgetAPI no contains method registIMEKey();, it contains in IMEShell.